# Remove WhiteSapce margin from responsive Page which is coming only on Safari not on Chorme , firefox

Tags: html, css, safari, responsive-design

I have developed a Responsive page with the help of @media query . 
 now when i check my page on iphone 6+ then there is some unwanted white space margin coming .

but page is working fine on chorme , firefox browser (developer mode also).

is there any CSS hack for safari so that i can remove that unwanted Whitespace margin from my page .

i have used below code in my responsive CSS

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me i was able to fix it by removing this from my stylesheet

```
*{
    padding: 0
}
```

**Another thing is WebKit stylesheet contains following 'margin' ,'padding' properties**

```
-webkit-margin-before:
-webkit-margin-end:
-webkit-margin-after:
-webkit-margin-start:

-webkit-padding-before:
-webkit-padding-end:
-webkit-padding-after:
-webkit-padding-start:
```

You can use this and customize accordingly for safari